# Calculating the odds of a specific outcome happening X amount of times in row?

Tags: probability

**How do i calculate the probability of a result happening X amount of times in a row?**

Imagine an event with 6 possible outcomes.
1st outcome has chance of 40%, 2nd has a chance of **20%**, 3rd 15%, 4th 10%, 5th 10%, 6th 5%.

Imagining the 2nd outcome has a 20% probability of happening, what are the odds of this outcome happening:

4 times in a row;
5 times in a row;
6 times in a row...

**Do i just multiply the odds of it happening by specific times it happens?**
So for 4 times in a row: 0.2 x 0.2 x 0.2 x 0.20 = 0.0016*100 = 0.16%

Is this it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In probability theory, there is a notion of independences. Two outcomes $A,B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$. That is to say, the fact that $A$ happens doesn't change the probability of $B$ happening and vice versa.

If the outcomes of your events are independent from each other, then, indeed, you can simply multiply the probabilities. Independence of outcomes is usually silently assumed for most school problems.

However, in real life many series of events aren't fully independent from each other. So you must be mindful of your model.